# ArangoDB .NET client query results are unsorted (OrderBy/Sort not working)

Tags: c#, .net, arangodb

I'm using ArangoDB 3.1.19 on Windows 10, with ArangoDB .NET client (0.7.60, tried 0.7.50 too (both from NuGET)).

When doing a LINQ query and using Sort() or OrderBy the results come back unsorted (in natural/chronological order).

The query that is bening generated appears to be correct; if I run it in the ArangoDB web interface it produced the expected results. But through the .NET client it is not.

Code:

```
[CollectionProperty(CollectionName = "users")]
class User
{
    [DocumentProperty(Identifier=IdentifierType.Key)]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ArangoDatabase.ChangeSetting(o => {
        o.Url = "http://localhost:8529";
        o.Database = "test";
        o.Logger = new ArangoDB.Client.DatabaseLogSharedSetting() {
            HttpRequest = true,
            Aql = true,
            Log = log => Debug.WriteLine(log),
        };
    });

    using (ArangoDatabase db = new ArangoDatabase())
    {
        var query = db.Query<User>()
            .OrderBy(o => o.Name);

        foreach (User user in query)
            Console.WriteLine(user.Name);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
jimmy
tony
ozzy
bjork
```

Debug Output:

```
==============================
5/10/2017 2:21:28 PM
creating an AQL query:
query:  for `o` in `users`  sort  `o`.`Name`  asc   return   `o`
==============================
5/10/2017 2:21:28 PM
sending http request:
url: http://localhost:8529/_db/test/_api/cursor
method: POST
'ArangoConsoleTest.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ArangoConsoleTest.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
data: {"query":" for `o` in `users`  sort  `o`.`Name`  asc   return   `o`","options":{"optimizer":{"rules":[]}}}
==============================
5/10/2017 2:21:30 PM
received http response:
url: http://localhost:8529/_db/test/_api/cursor
status-code: Created
data: "{\"result\":[{\"_key\":\"jimmy\",\"_id\":\"users/jimmy\",\"_rev\":\"_U68WDkm---\",\"name\":\"jimmy\",\"age\":1},{\"_key\":\"1193\",\"_id\":\"users/1193\",\"_rev\":\"_U676wfm---\",\"name\":\"tony\",\"age\":42},{\"_key\":\"1432\",\"_id\":\"users/1432\",\"_rev\":\"_U674_PS---\",\"name\":\"ozzy\",\"age\":69},{\"_key\":\"1387\",\"_id\":\"users/1387\",\"_rev\":\"_U673Suy---\",\"name\":\"bjork\",\"age\":50}],\"hasMore\":false,\"cached\":false,\"extra\":{\"stats\":{\"writesExecuted\":0,\"writesIgnored\":0,\"scannedFull\":4,\"scannedIndex\":0,\"filtered\":0,\"executionTime\":0.0010030269622802734},\"warnings\":[]},\"error\":false,\"code\":201}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In my Collection (in ArangoDB) the Age and Name fields are all lowercase (age and name), but in my model class (.NET) they're Age/Name.

The queries weren't erroring-out so I figured the names were case-insenstive, but apparently not when it comes to LINQ stuff or sorting.

Adding [DocumentProperty(PropertyName = "name")] to my Name property fixed the sorting problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Phuo answer for cause of the problem, another solution is if the member name is in camelcase form you can use:

```
[DocumentProperty(Naming = NamingConvention.ToCamelCase)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Or if all members are in camelcase, use class attribute for the naming convention

```
[CollectionProperty(Naming= NamingConvention.ToCamelCase)]
public class User
{ ... }
```

this way all members name will translate to their camelcase form (`User -> user`) in load docs, save docs, AQL queries and other operations.